Firestore Rule based on field value
I'm new to these rules and there is something fundamental I don't understand. The following rule does not work:
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /usernames/{username} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /universes/{universe}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && 
        get(/databases/$(database)/documents/universes/$(universe)).data.isPublic == true;
    }
  }
}

Yet if I replace $(universe) with the name of an existing document (basically hard-coding it) it does work?! I thought $(universe) provided a variable to the name of the universe in question but alas!!
The query that does not work with $(universe) but does work with a hard-coded document name is:
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('universes').snapshots()

With the following error if set to $(universe) vs an existing document name:

W/Firestore(27925): (25.0.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(universes order by name);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

What I want is for someone to be able to read or write any document in a universe that is public. Thanks!

Please edit the question to show the query that doesn't work the way you expect.  Security rules don't mean anything until they are paired with a query that they should allow.

Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

Firestore security rules are not filters.  Please read that documentation carefully to understand the issue.
Your query is asking for all of the documents in the universes collection, without a filter.  However, it seems you are expecting your rules to filter out some of the documents based on their contents.  That's not how security rules work. Rules cannot filter documents from the results of a query.  They can only ensure that an appropriate filter has been applied to the query.
If you want to get all of the documents in universes where isPublic is true, you will need to apply that filter on the query itself in order to match the requirements of the rule:
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('universes')
    .where("universes", isEqualTo: true)
    .snapshots()

Your rule should also probably be this in order to match the query:
    match /universes/{universe}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && resource.data.isPublic == true;
    }


Thanks! I read that the security rules aren't a filter but it just seemed like that's how it would work, hah. So the query is belt and the rule is the suspenders. Makes me think after a simple auth check rule the app should just control displaying what it should and not deal with these rules, but that's probably blasphemy!
